# Wrong values of thrust::transform output

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to transform a `float3` array by using containers into a container of a specific structure. Code below:

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

// Ouput structure for thrust::transform
struct cloud_point_index_idx {
  unsigned int idx;
  float3 cloud_point;

  cloud_point_index_idx(unsigned int idx_, float3 cloud_point_) :
    idx(idx_), cloud_point(cloud_point_) {}

  bool operator < (const cloud_point_index_idx &p) const {
    return (idx < p.idx);
  }
};
// Functor for thrust::transform
struct point2voxelcentroid {
  float3 leaf_size;
  int min_x, min_y, min_z;

  point2voxelcentroid(float3 leaf_size,int min_x, int min_y, int min_z) {
    this->leaf_size = leaf_size;
    this->min_x = min_x; this->min_y = min_y; this->min_z = min_z;
  }

  __host__ __device__
  cloud_point_index_idx operator()(const float3 point) const {
    int ijk0 = static_cast<int>(floor(point.x / leaf_size.x) -
      static_cast<float>(min_x));
    int ijk1 = static_cast<int>(floor(point.y / leaf_size.y) -
      static_cast<float>(min_y));
    int ijk2 = static_cast<int>(floor(point.z / leaf_size.z) -
      static_cast<float>(min_z));

    int voxel_idx = ijk0 + ijk1 + ijk2;
    return cloud_point_index_idx(static_cast<unsigned int>(voxel_idx), point);
  }
};

int main() { // Example
  int num_points = 5;
  float3 data[5] = {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 1, -5}, {-1, 3, -2}, {-5, -2, 0}}; // Set the data
  int min_b_[3] = {-5, -2, -5};
  float3 leaf_size = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
  thrust::device_vector<float3> d_ptr(data, data + num_points); // Wrap it into a device_vector
  thrust::device_vector<cloud_point_index_idx> voxel_idx_vector; // Output
  voxel_idx_vector.reserve(num_points);
  thrust::transform(
    thrust::device,
    d_ptr.begin(), d_ptr.end(),
    voxel_idx_vector.begin(),
    point2voxelcentroid(leaf_size, min_b_[0], min_b_[1], min_b_[2]));

  thrust::host_vector<cloud_point_index_idx> indices; // Host vector to verify
  indices.reserve(num_points);
  thrust::copy(voxel_idx_vector.begin(), voxel_idx_vector.end(), indices.begin()); // Copy device to host

  // Print out values
  std::cout << "\n---\nAfter assignment\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
    std::cout << "Voxel idx: " << indices[i].idx << ". Point: [" << indices[i].cloud_point.x << ", "
       << indices[i].cloud_point.y << ", " << indices[i].cloud_point.z << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I inspected my functor values and they seem to correctly parse the data but when I print my host_vector I get really weird values, nothing related to what my output must be. I suspect I'm not initializing my output host/device vectors correctly. I tried other methods to initialize them but they all give me errors when compiling. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you are going to post a wall of code you want help with, please make sure it is an [MCVE]. What you have posted can't be compiled and I can't tell you what is wrong with code like this which is incomplete.

Comment: I edited the code with a reproducible example.

Comment: when I compile your code, I get a warning "warning: calling a `__host__` function from a `__host__ __device__` function is not allowed"  Do you get that warning anywhere?  If so, you should not ignore it.

Comment: The first obvious problem I see is that you are statically casting negative values to unsigned int.

Comment: In addition, you are also confused about the concept of `.reserve()` with vectors.  It's not doing what you think it is doing.  The **size** of that vector is unchanged by `.reserve()`.  As a result, you have 2 vectors that have zero size, and that won't work with thrust.  Thrust algorithms do not automatically resize vectors for you.  To fix that, you will need to provide an additional constructor for `cloud_point_index_idx`, and eliminate the `.reserve()` calls, and initially create the vectors in question to have the appropriate size (`num_points`).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I do get that warning. Can you explain why does that show up? From the terminal shows is in the line where I use `static_cast`. Should I not use that?

Comment: @RobertCrovella regarding your second comment, could you explain a bit more what is the kind of constructor I need to create please?

Comment: @talonmies thank you for pointing that out. I had the wrong concept on how this was being used.

Comment: Any code that is expected to run on the GPU device must be marked with either `__device__` or `__global__`.  (This is CUDA 101 type knowledge, not unique or specific to thrust).  In this line of code, you are calling a constructor:  `return cloud_point_index_idx(static_cast<unsigned int>(voxel_idx), point);`  Now, that line of code is called from the device in a proper `__device__` marked routine.  However the constructor it calls is not marked with the `__device__` keyword.  You should mark that constructor with `__host__ __device__` so the compiler generates both types of code for it.

Comment: When you remove the `.reserve()` lines, and modify the thrust vector instantiations to have a default size `(num_points)`, you will then observe compile errors.  This is because you have not provided a constructor for a `cloud_point_index_idx` object that takes no arguments.  The vector instantiation calls/needs such a constructor.  Something like this should work: `__host__ __device__ cloud_point_index_idx() {};`  Do you see how that differs from the constructor you already have? It requires no arguments, and that is type needed to initialize your vectors.

Comment: Regarding the previous comment, the compiler will produce an error of the form `error: no instance of constructor "cloud_point_index_idx::cloud_point_index_idx" matches the argument list...` That is your clue that your provided constructor for that object doesn't match the one that is needed.  And if you follow the compiler trail it will eventually point to the line where you are instantiating the vectors in question.  Since that vector instantiation requires object initialization, and evidently no arguments are provided for such, its evident that a constructor is needed that uses no arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here, but the most severe is the use of `reserve` which doesn't actually allocate memory for a thrust container.

What you need to do is define a default constructor and explicitly allocate a size at instantiation. Something like this:

```
struct cloud_point_index_idx {
  int idx;
  float3 cloud_point;

  cloud_point_index_idx()=default;

  __host__ __device__
  cloud_point_index_idx(unsigned int idx_, float3 cloud_point_) :
    idx(idx_), cloud_point(cloud_point_) {}

  __host__ __device__
  bool operator < (const cloud_point_index_idx &p) const {
    return (idx < p.idx);
  }
};
```

(requires `-std=c++11`) will define a default constructor on both device and host which the container must call during initialization of each class instance.

This modification of your code works for me:

```
$ cat bodgey.cu

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#include <iostream>

// Ouput structure for thrust::transform
struct cloud_point_index_idx {
  int idx;
  float3 cloud_point;

  cloud_point_index_idx()=default;

  __host__ __device__
  cloud_point_index_idx(unsigned int idx_, float3 cloud_point_) :
    idx(idx_), cloud_point(cloud_point_) {}

  __host__ __device__
  bool operator < (const cloud_point_index_idx &p) const {
    return (idx < p.idx);
  }
};
// Functor for thrust::transform
struct point2voxelcentroid {
  float3 leaf_size;
  int min_x, min_y, min_z;

  point2voxelcentroid(float3 leaf_size,int min_x, int min_y, int min_z) {
    this->leaf_size = leaf_size;
    this->min_x = min_x; this->min_y = min_y; this->min_z = min_z;
  }

  __host__ __device__
  cloud_point_index_idx operator()(const float3 point) const {
    int ijk0 = static_cast<int>(floor(point.x / leaf_size.x) -
      static_cast<float>(min_x));
    int ijk1 = static_cast<int>(floor(point.y / leaf_size.y) -
      static_cast<float>(min_y));
    int ijk2 = static_cast<int>(floor(point.z / leaf_size.z) -
      static_cast<float>(min_z));

    int voxel_idx = ijk0 + ijk1 + ijk2;
    return cloud_point_index_idx(voxel_idx, point);
  }
};

int main() { // Example
  int num_points = 5;
  float3 data[5] = {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 1, -5}, {-1, 3, -2}, {-5, -2, 0}}; // Set the data
  int min_b_[3] = {-5, -2, -5};
  float3 leaf_size = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
  thrust::device_vector<float3> d_ptr(data, data + num_points); // Wrap it into a device_vector
  thrust::device_vector<cloud_point_index_idx> voxel_idx_vector(num_points); // Output
  thrust::transform(
    thrust::device,
    d_ptr.begin(), d_ptr.end(),
    voxel_idx_vector.begin(),
    point2voxelcentroid(leaf_size, min_b_[0], min_b_[1], min_b_[2]));

  thrust::host_vector<cloud_point_index_idx> indices(num_points); // Host vector to verify
  thrust::copy(voxel_idx_vector.begin(), voxel_idx_vector.end(), indices.begin()); // Copy device to host

  // Print out values
  std::cout << "\n---\nAfter assignment\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
    std::cout << "Voxel idx: " << indices[i].idx << ". Point: [" << indices[i].cloud_point.x << ", "
       << indices[i].cloud_point.y << ", " << indices[i].cloud_point.z << std::endl;
  }
}

$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o bodgey bodgey.cu 

$ ./bodgey 

---
After assignment
Voxel idx: 18. Point: [1, 0, 2
Voxel idx: 24. Point: [2, 1, 3
Voxel idx: 6. Point: [1, 1, -5
Voxel idx: 12. Point: [-1, 3, -2
Voxel idx: -2. Point: [-5, -2, 0
```